# MySQL use inner join in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables, the unique id's in each table are the same in both tables.
How do I go about joining the data from both tables together in php?

When I normally pull data I do it like this:

```
    $get_board_array = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id_to = '$id' ");
      while($posts = mysql_fetch_array($get_board_array))
        {
          $post_id = $get_post['post_id']; 
          $html_output .= "<p>".$post_id."</p>";
        }
```

As for pulling the data from separate tables and not getting it all mixed up, I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
$get_arrayA = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE age = '36' ");
  while($dataA = mysql_fetch_array($get_arrayA))
  {

      $dataA_id = $dataA['id'];
      $dataA_firstName = $dataA['FirstName'];

  foreach($dataA_id)
    {
      $get_arrayB = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tableB where id='".$dataA_id."'");
      while($dataB = mysql_fetch_array($get_arrayB))
      {

      $dataB_lastName = $dataB['LastName'];

      $html_output .= "<p>".$dataA_firstName.$dataB_lastName"</p>";

      echo $html_output;
      }
   }
}
```

Or would this be just too weird of a thing?

I know how to do it within SQL using inner join but how do I do something like that in PHP and output html?

Comment: Nested queries are bad! Have a look at [MySQL JOINs](http://mysqljoin.com/) instead. Think about it - you're going to run a query for every row returned by the outer query. This is monstrously slow whereas a `JOIN` is only one query.

Comment: your statement: `$dataA_id = $dataA['id'];` is merely updating the variable's value, instead of creating an array

Comment: If you know how to do it in SQL, then you know how to do it in "PHP". You shouldn't be selecting `*` and you shouldn't be nesting queries in loops. Pull as much data up front as you can.

Comment: @JamWaffles OHHHH I was doing it very wrong, I couldn;t get the JOIn to work in php so tried the nested way and I got that to kind of work but I figured that it's a stupid way of going about it. The tutorial I found was from 2007, this one you sent looks much more promising

Comment: @MetalFrog This makes sense, I just tried it again using the tutorial waffles sent me and I got it to work. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @JamWaffles can you post that as an answer please so i can accept it? :)

Comment: We all start somewhere. Glad you're picking up on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because of you misguide use of wildcard (*) characters. **STOP THAT !!** This is what happens when arrogant php developers imagine that they do not need to learn SQL. If you need something , then select it.

```
SELECT 
    foo.foo_id, 
    foo.data as paramX , 
    bar.type,
    bar.something_else
FROM foo
    INNER JOIN bar USING (foo_id)
WHERE
    foo.state = 'open'
AND bar.type = 3
```

Comment: `USING (foo_id)` is shorthand for `ON foo.foo_id = bar.foo_id`

Comment: I had no idea you could select just 1 column. I read a book back in January on PHP they basically gave like 1 chapter on SQL every query using SELECT *. Making this site for me and my friends the past couple weeks when I have time off work, I've learned so much more about SQL it's crazy. Thanks a bunch for this, anything to optimize my queries helps out alot!

Comment: @user1053263 , there very good books for SQL. Read any that deals only with MySQL , and then get [SQL Antipatterns](http://pragprog.com/book/bksqla/sql-antipatterns) .. that's for advanced uses. All the the books that claim to teach you both MySQL and PHP are no better then "Learn C in 3 days" titles.

Answer (score 1):

This (I'm just guessing the schema and your needs) could be a better query for your situation:

```
SELECT a.id,a.FirstName,b.LastName 
FROM tableA a 
JOIN tableB b ON b.id = a.id
WHERE a.age = '36'
```

Comment: there is a problem with your join condition

Comment: @tereško feel free to make any correction you deem useful. I don't know what kind of join does he needs. Maybe an INNER is better, yes

Comment: true , but this one would be joining on both primary keys .. assuming he has primary keys

Comment: Well, looking at the code it seems he's using the ID from the first select as a condition for the second queries, so I guessed like this; but as I said, without other info I'm just using a "common" situation

Comment: Yeah the IDs on both of the tables are unique corresponding and they are set as primary and auto increment.